# static image/media files in django

Tags: django

i am unable to load static files with django in my template my files are shown below

## Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'Theme'
```

]

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
STATIC_DIR,
]
```

## Template/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First App</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello this is index.html!</h1>
<img src="{% static 'images/mark.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
</body>
</html>
```

project Direstory

[This is the projec t directory`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX46k.png)

Comment: Did you add the static urls to the `urls.py`?

Comment: No i haven't done that iv'e two urls.py one for main project and another for app in which i have to add this url

Answer (score 0):

Add these code also in your main url file

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and in setting add this line too

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

Answer (score 0):

`STATICFILES_DIR` list should be named **STATICFILES_DIRS**.

[In development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) when you run with `runserver` and `DEBUG=True` it is enough.

---

To serve staticfiles [in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#deployment):

- usage of external web-server (in production you will most probably have one or web-proxy in front of django) is recommended. Call `collectstatic`
  and serve the resulted static_root dir with web-server
- Or you can upload them to CDN (AWS S3, CLoudflare)
- Or it is possible to make django serve them using [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)
- least recommended but still possible - serving with django as is development by adding static urls

Comment: Thank you
iv'e just replaced STATICFILES_DIR with STATICFILES_DIRS